# using a parameter in a function without previously declaring it

Tags: python, pandas, variables

Appreciate this is a simple question,

Using the tutorial here https://introml.analyticsdojo.com/notebooks/nb-04-10-pca.html

with this code below.

How are df and dv used as parameters in the function when they are not previously declared?

Thanks for any help

```
import os
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpi-techfundamentals/spring2019-materials/master/input/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rpi-techfundamentals/spring2019-materials/master/input/test.csv')

print(train.columns, test.columns)

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

cat_features = ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Embarked']
num_features =  [ 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare'  ]


def preprocess(df, num_features, cat_features, dv):
    features = cat_features + num_features
    if dv in df.columns:
      y = df[dv]
    else:
      y=None 
    #Address missing variables
    print("Total missing values before processing:", df[features].isna().sum().sum() )
  
    imp_mode = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
    df[cat_features]=imp_mode.fit_transform(df[cat_features] )
    imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
    df[num_features]=imp_mean.fit_transform(df[num_features])
    print("Total missing values after processing:", df[features].isna().sum().sum() )
   
    X = pd.get_dummies(df[features], columns=cat_features, drop_first=True)
    return y,X

y, X =  preprocess(train, num_features, cat_features, 'Survived')
test_y, test_X = preprocess(test, num_features, cat_features, 'Survived')
```

Comment: They are part of the function signature - they are argument names. When you call the function with `y, X =  preprocess(train, num_features, cat_features, 'Survived')` then that's where you set their values in the scope of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you don't have to declare variables to be able to use them. The interpreter assigns the type of the variable as you run your program, the best practice is still to declare them so that you can be sure that in that variable there is the type that you want.

In this case 'df' is train which is the csv file used and 'dv' is the word "Survived". The for loop searches within all the csv files columns for the word Survived and if there is a correspondence it then adds to the csv files in that index.

You can see how it works better [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) which, in my opinion could help you clear your doubts.